# Unnatural amount of views on a question

Tags: support, hot-network-questions

I asked a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83145/how-did-james-potter-become-head-boy) today , and in about 6 hours it got about 850 views ( as it reads in the description ).

I wanted to know whether its a glitch since none of the other questions that were asked today got so many views.

UPDATE 1

It just became 954 !!

UPDATE 2

Just for the happy beginning , it crossed 1000 :)

Comment: It probably ended up on the "hot network topics" bar on the right.

Comment: @Richard Oh okay thank you.So these Hot Network Questions change in some time intervals ? And do you know the criteria of this selcetion (just curious).

Comment: They change periodically. I don't know the mechanism (other than that it's based on a algorithm). I'm sure someone will be along shortly to quote you the relevant bits from the main stack exchange site that explain it.

Comment: @Richard Thank you . Just an offtopic question, is the scifi meta site duller in look than the main site ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confirmed - your question made [the Network Hot Questions List](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), so it's showing up for users across the network

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you . Never imagined that on the first day I would squeeze into 'Top Network Users' :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible to generate tons of traffic for a specific question.

When I posted this question [What states did the 2 extra stars on the American flag represent in Star Trek TNG "The Royale"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80025/what-states-did-the-2-extra-stars-on-the-american-flag-represent-in-star-trek-tn) to reddit, I received the [Publicist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/publicist) badge within 10 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the update . I wonder why I didnt get this badge then . 2500+ views must gather 1000+ unique IPs right ?

Comment: @stud You don't just get it for posting a question, you have to share it (using the share link) in order to get credit for traffic. Then people using the share link are counted towards the badges.